# Exporting membership data including chosen price set

Tags: price-sets

Our charity offers a range of memberships for organisations with the price based on their size. For each type of membership we have a price set including 3 options. So you can be a service provider (small, medium, large); a training provider (small, medium, large) or a supporter organisation (small, medium, large).

We have recently moved over to CIVI want to invoice members who have just joined and those who are due for renewal (yearly).

We want to be able to create invoices using a mailmerge from excel  including info like organisation's name, member type (service provider, trainer, support org), member start date, end date, and of course what it will cost them to renew assuming they are still the same price set ie (small, medium, large). We can search memberships to find those who are due for renewal but we can't find out what price set they chose when they joined.

We tried to export data but can't find price set as a field under member data or payments/contributions. I can't even see it when clicking into an individual member's details. The price sets are active as we've tested joining and you need to select the option - it works for PayPal but we can't process PayLater at present. I've noticed when creating profiles it says that contribution and member data cannot be included on the same profile. So wondered if that is part of the problem. Is there a work around?

We're on CIVI 4.5.8

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If I am not wrong - you have imported data from your previous system to civicrm and started using price set. But you couldn't find the old price set in the new system because you couldn't view membership amount in the membership record --

This problem is due to data import you have civicrm_membership but you haven't created civicrm_membership_contribution records.

while creating contribution records and line item you will be adding price set Id and price field Id correctly. then this will get picked up in civicrm price set